# What is the actual album name of Justin Timberlake's The 20/20 Experience (deluxe) album?

Tags: release, album-title

I am confused about the actual album name, is it "The 20/20 Experience" or "The 20/20 Experience (Deluxe Version)" like how it's listed on streaming services?

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article about the 2013 album ['The 20/20 Experience'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_20/20_Experience)  has "The 20/20 Experience" as the actual title.

From the same source, the Deluxe edition and the Chinese and Japanese standard editions have two additional tracks : "Dress On" and "Body Count".

Further information about the multiple formats for this release is on [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Justin-Timberlake-The-2020-Experience/master/533208)